# Extract Email Body with inline attachment in base64

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, inline

As part of our system, we are extracting Mail messages from Exchange Inbox Folder.
All goes well , except the point of extracting the Email Body. 
Email body saved as an HTML however CIDS ( INLINE Attachments) are required to be kept in the HTML document as Base64.

how this is possible to do ? 
Any examples?

```
private void downloadAttachment(Part part, String folderPath) throws Exception {
    String disPosition = part.getDisposition();
    String fileName = part.getFileName();
    String decodedText = null;
    logger.info("Disposition type :: " + disPosition);
    logger.info("Attached File Name :: " + fileName);

    if (disPosition != null && disPosition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is ATTACHMENT type.");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + decodedText);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    } else if (fileName != null && disPosition == null) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is Null type but file name is valid.  Possibly inline attchment");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + decodedText);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    } else if (fileName == null && disPosition == null) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is Null type but file name is null. It is email body.");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + "mail.html");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    }


}
     protected int saveEmailAttachment(File saveFile, Part part) throws Exception {

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    int ret = 0, count = 0;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveFile));
        part.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(saveFile));

    } finally {
        try {
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            logger.error("Error while closing the stream.", ioe);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Have you written any code?  Presumably, you at least have a [Message](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Message.html) object, yes?

Comment: If the data is already in the html body as inline base64 data, you can read it directly from the message.  If it is not, and you want to transform the html content of the message to include the attachments as inline data, you'll have to do that yourself; JavaMail won't help you, but it will allow you to access all the pieces of the message so you can transform them yourself.

Comment: Hello
Yes, I have in the Message object and im saving the attachments on disk,
However , the BODY HTML file has square (EMPTY CID) on the HTML itself , means there are no images on the HTML which are INLINE.

Do you guys have any example which can light us how to solve it?